# How to get usage stats for "current day" using usageStatsManager in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, usagestatsmanager

Objective:
 
Need to get the usage stats for today (total time for which the device was used today) ie. 12.00 am to current time.

Problem:
1.I get today's time + some other non explainable time
2.Non explainable time stamps(start and end of the usage stats as retrieved by the getTimestamp methods)

The time bucket is not relevant. I give the start time as 12.00 am and the end time as current time, but I get completely irrelevant ".firstTimeStamp" and ".lastTimeStamp" (which supposedly return the beginning and end of the usage stats data) for the usage statistics.

*already done the permission granting part, here is the function I'm using to get total time in minutes.

```
fun showtime(){

    val time=Calendar.getInstance()
    time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0)
    time.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0)

    val start=time.timeInMillis
    val end= System.currentTimeMillis()

    val usageStatsManager = getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
    var stats = usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(start,end)

    var x:Long=0
    var ft:Long=0
    var v:Long=0
    var l:Long=0

    for ((key,value) in stats) {
        ft=value.totalTimeInForeground/60000
          textField1.append("$key = $ft mins")
            textField1.append("\n")
            x=x+ft
        v=value.firstTimeStamp
        l=value.lastTimeStamp
    }

    textView.setText("YOU SPENT $x mins.")
    textView2.setText("${Date(v)} to \n${Date(l)}")
}
```

As an example, when the above code runs at Wed 12 Dec 12.40 am, the result is:
(in textView):
YOU SPENT 90 mins
(in textView2):
Tue 11 Dec 16:23:19 GMT +05:30 2018 to
Tue 11 Dec 19:38:45 GMT +05:30 2018

How can I use my phone for 90 mins in just 40 mins?
And what does those apparently irrelevant timestamps mean?
Am I doing something wrong to achieve my objective?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get my app screen time on a hourly basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615457/how-can-i-get-my-app-screen-time-on-a-hourly-basis)

Comment: Yes it does. Event based method is pretty accurate and can be used for the same purpose. But the relevance of userStatsManager remains and it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I actually experience a similar problem:

According to my understanding of the documentation `firstTimeStamp` and `lastTimeStamp` should give the "beginning (end) of the time range this UsageStats represents".

They differ however from what I give as an argument in `queryAndAggregateUsageStats` as `beginTime` and `endTime`.

Also the result for the `totalTimeInForeground`seems  rather give back a result for the timespan given by `firstTimeStamp` / `lastTimeStamp` than for the requested one.

I filled a bug with google for this, please have a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118564471.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed several problems with your approach.

- You are missing `time.set(Calendar.SECOND,0)` and `time.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0)`
- Precision is lost in the division `ft=value.totalTimeInForeground/60000`

I would recommend [*Java Time (ThreeTenBP)*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to handle *DateTime* and *Duration* more accurately. I create a new function to compare and indeed the results are different.

```
fun showtime2(){
    val start = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
    val end = ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant().toEpochMilli()

    val usageStatsManager = getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
    val stats = usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(start, end)

    val total = Duration.ofMillis(stats.values.map { it.totalTimeInForeground }.sum())
    println("YOU SPENT ${total.toMinutes()} mins.")
}
```

**Your output**

YOU SPENT 577 mins.

**My output**

YOU SPENT 582 mins.